# PHP - Errors with DOmdocument

Tags: php

Why I am getting the following error

```
 Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object
```

Error happens on following line:

```
  $title = $htm->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

when I run the following code:

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument();

  foreach ($all as $blog) {

    sleep(1);

    $htm = $dom->loadHTML(fetch_url('http://' . rtrim(preg_replace('/^http:\/\//i', '', $blog['blogurl']), '/')));

    if ($htm) {

      //check TITLE

      $title = $htm->getElementsByTagName('title');

      $title = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;

      if (preg_match('/private/i', $title)) {

        private_blog($blog['id']);

        $title = null;
        unset($title);
        gc_collect_cycles();
        continue;
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `$htm` with `$dom` in that line:

```
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
         ^^^^
```

to further improve rename the `$htm` variable in the other line above:

```
$loadResult = $dom->loadHTML(fetch_url('http://' . rtrim(preg_replace('/^http:\/\//i', '', $blog['blogurl']), '/')));
^^^^^^^^^^^
if ($loadResult) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```